# Mousedown-mouseup creates divs exponentially

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a simple "drawing" interface using Jquery, where one can draw shapes in a div. I am using mousedown-mouseup event handlers to achieve this shape creation. On every mousedown-mouseup, a shape must be drawn on the 'canvas' div. I use separate handlers for mousedown and mouseup instead of just a click because I want to make the shape resizeable before mouseup.

**THE PROBLEM:**
In my ***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtgye/m6zgh5r3/2/)***, there is a space on the left where I log every click to see how many shapes are created.
At first click, it works fine. I get a nice shape. However, on the succeeding attemps, a single mousedown-mouseup seems to create more divs 'at the background'. The log shows additional divs for each click while you only see a single shape for each click.

I wonder why is this happening?

***JS:***

```
var num=0;
$('.draw').mousedown(function(e){
    var newDiv = null;
    newDiv = $('<div>').addClass('rec').css({
        'top': e.pageY,
        'left': e.pageX
    }).appendTo(this);
    $(this).mouseup(function(){
        num++
        $('.elems').append($('<p>').text('rec '+num));

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because for every mousedown event you're attaching a new mouseup listener,
you want to move that event binding out of the mousedown listener.

```
var num=0;
$('.draw')
    .mousedown(function(e){
        var newDiv = null;
        newDiv = $('<div>').addClass('rec').css({
            'top': e.pageY,
            'left': e.pageX
        }).appendTo(this);
    })
    .mouseup(function(){
        num++;
        $('.elems').append($('<p>').text('rec '+num));
    })
;
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I am thinking to put the 'mouseup' inside for some reason, but since it creates some conflict I just go with this.

Comment: Oh, by the way. The reason I did my code like that is because at `mouseup`, I am trying to use a variable which was created within `mousedown`. This variable won't be accessible if I chain the `mouseup` since it is locally created within the `mousedown`.

Comment: If you're considering assigning it inside the `mousedown` event to have access to the created div I would advise to use a second "global" variable(like `num`) to store a reference to the currently "edited" `div` or adding a class `latest` to it.

Comment: @jacelysh See my comment above this one. Also, as a side note you're talking about a "drawing" interface, you may want to consider using the `canvas` element for it, since DOM insertions will become very slow after a certain amount of elements is reached. This  is due to browser redraw and refloating on every insert.

Comment: Yah, i considered using `canvas` too. I just came up with this thing when I am trying to use JS to build this interface. I will just use a global variable then. Thanks a lot. You're a big help.

Answer (score 2):

See http://jsfiddle.net/m6zgh5r3/3/

It's happenning because on every mousedown you're binding to mouseup again.

Just adding

```
 $(this).unbind("mouseup");
```

fixes it.

Comment: While your solution "solves" the problem, its totally unnecessary to bind and unbind this event listener.

Comment: I agree with LJ_1102. This totally works, although I never thought of unbinding mouseup. @LJ_1102, how did you say that it's unnecessary to unbind this event listener?..

Comment: With `totally unnecessary to bind and unbind` i meant the fact of "switching" this event listener on and off. Its should be sufficient to bind it once and leave it like that. Poor wording on my side.